# Django: How can I access and display details about the single "child" in the one-to-many relationship?

Tags: python, django

I have two models - the Company and Department. The Company can have many Departments - this is all connected with Foreign Key and works as expected. I have URLs and templates/views nicely setup and I can add the Company and then I can add Depratments to it. I am also able to access and create new Departments and assign them to the Company.

To see, say 5 last companies and last 5 Departments I have in the system I use this:

```
    class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    model = Company
    template_name = 'company/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_company_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        """Return the last five created companies."""
        return Company.objects.order_by('company_name')[:5]

class DeptIndexView(generic.ListView):
    model = Department
    template_name = 'department/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_department_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        """Return the last five created companies."""
        return Department.objects.order_by('dept_name')[:5]
```

And here are the models from models.py

```
class Company(models.Model):
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    company_dba = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "companies"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.company_name

    # on submit click on the company entry page, it redirects to the url below.
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('company:index')


class Department(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    dept_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    dept_code = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.dept_name

    # on submit click on the department entry page, it redirects to the url below.
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('company:index')
```

My urls.py file looks like this

```
app_name = 'company'
urlpatterns = [
    # Company management views
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    path('add/', views.CompanyEntry.as_view(), name='add'),
    path('update/<int:pk>/', views.CompanyUpdate.as_view(), name='update'),
    path('delete/<int:pk>/', views.CompanyDelete.as_view(), name='delete'),

    #Department management views
    path('<int:pk>/department/', views.DeptIndexView.as_view(), name='dept_index'),
    path('<int:pk>/department/add/', views.DeptEntry.as_view(), name='dept_add'),
    path('<int:pk>/department/<int:fk>/', views.DeptDetailView, name='dept_detail'),
]
```

The issue here is that I don't know how to configure URL/path so that I can access details about one single Department.

I am trying to get something like http://127.0.0.1:8000/company/1/department/2/ where 2 is the id of the Department model.

And that last line in the code above doesn't seem to be working.

Instead, I am getting this as an error:

TypeError at /company/1/department/2/

**init**() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/company/1/department/2/
Django Version:     2.2.4
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:

**init**() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Exception Location:     /Users/ABC/DjangoHR/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in _get_response, line 113

Comment: Is this a typo in your urlconf: `<int:pk>/department/<int:fk/>`? The slash in `int:fk/` should probably be outside of the `<>` definition?

Comment: it was, you are right, I fixed it and now I'm getting different error, I will update the question

Comment: `get_absolute_url` for `class Department` has a typo, shoud be `return reverse('company:dept_detail')`

Comment: thanks, appreciate the catch!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out - I missed .as_view()

```
path('<int:pk>/department/<int:fk>/', views.DeptDetailView.as_view(), name='dept_detail'),
```

Thank you all for help and comments!